# What is the German term for contrary words like "aber", "jedoch", "dennoch"

Tags: single-word-request, subordinate-clause

What is - if there is - the German term for words that indicate a contrary "Nebensatz"?

Comment: These words don't connect a main clause with a subordinate clause (Nebensatz), they connect two main clauses. An example for a conjunction which is used for contrary subordinate clauses is *obwohl*. Such subordinary clauses are called *Konzessivsätze*.

Answer (score 3):

Words such as *aber*, *jedoch*, and *dennoch* are called [*Konjunktion*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konjunktion_(Wortart)), in plural *Konjunktionen*.

Comment: That's too general. There are many other *Konjunktionen* which are quite different from those mentioned in the question.